# How to remove function app hostname when the function app is already deleted?

Tags: azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I destroyed my Azure function app via Terraform like this:

```
terraform destroy
```

But looks like it didn't remove the hostname, now I can't register a new function app with the same hostname. When I try to remove via Azure CLI:

```
az functionapp config hostname delete
```

It says the function app doesn't exist which is true of course. What should I do?

Comment: You dont need to delete the hostname. When you delete the function it delete the function app + the hostname

Comment: I know it still exist because I can't create the function with the same hostname, said it already exists: `The name "************" used for the Function App needs to be globally unique and isn't available: Hostname '************' already exists. Please select a different name.`

Comment: how long did you wait before trying to recreate the resour e ?

Comment: I tried immediately 5 hours ago and now I try again, the hostname still isn't released.

Comment: could you try again with a new hostname ???? maybe be someone took the same

Comment: Looks like that's the case. I just destroy and apply another function name with no problem. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If you share the old host name, I can verify whether it is in fact claimed or whether there is some different issue that's preventing it from being used.

Comment: `eli-azure-functions` I think.

Comment: @Khoi Did you try `terraform refresh` ?

Comment: I didn't try that. When I try a new hostname I could destroy and recreate freely without this command though.

Comment: Just came across the same issue. Almost 6 years later. It's not a terraform issue, but Azure's backend. Additional ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/103411/azure-function-app-host-name-already-exist-(non-ex